# PHP 8.1 imageavif(): AVIF image support has been disabled

Tags: php, gd, avif

PHP 8.1.4 (Installed via remi repo) runing on CentOS 8 Stream

I tested avif support on the machine:

```
php -i | grep AVIF
AVIF Support => enabled

php -r 'echo gd_info()["AVIF Support"];'
1

if (function_exists("imageavif")) {echo "tes";}else{echo "no";}
yes
```

It looks ok, but when I use "imageavif" function, I got this warning:

> **Warning**:  imageavif(): AVIF image support has been disabled

I'm confused... Tests saids "AVIF Support => enabled", and scripts saids disabled...

How can I enable it??

My tries:

```
php -r 'var_dump(imageavif(imagecreatetruecolor(8, 8), "/tmp/test"));'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 8 (and 9) don't have libavif, so the support cannot be enabled in libgd.

BTW, by design, the function is always there, but fails.

AVIF format is available using the **imagick** or **vips** extensions using the **libheif** library

Using my repository, you need

- php-pecl-imagick-im7, ImageMagick7-heic and libheif from [rpmfusion.org](https://rpmfusion.org/)

or

- php-pecl-vips, vips-heif and libheif from [rpmfusion.org](https://rpmfusion.org/)

Comment: Thank you! 

I tried "dnf install libavif-devel" and came out an error: "Unable to find a match: libavif-devel"

Seems libavif only avaible on Debian/Ubuntu & Fedora/RHLE? Is there any way I install it on CentOS?

Comment: Alternative solution using imagick/vips way added to above answer

Comment: To have lilbavif in CentOS, you can try to ask on https://bugzilla.redhat.com/ to have it added to EPEL repository

Comment: See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/2071940